# Using the values of variable in the objective function before optimizing: Python Gurobi

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am facing a problem to multiply a term in objective function. My objective function is :

```
\begin{equation}
    min \sum_{t=1}^T p_{t} * (1+r) * y_{t}    
\end{equation}
```

where $p$ is the price, $y$ is the quantity (decision variable) and $r$ is the price surcharge. $t$ is the index for time periods.

The problem is that the value of $r$ depends on between which interval the value of $y$ (decision variable) lies as shown by the following piecewise function.

```
\begin{equation}
    \r_t (Y_t) = 
    \begin{cases}
        % s_0
        0 & \mathrm{if }\; Y_t \leq b_0 \\
        % s_1
        0.05 & \mathrm{if }\; b_0 < Y_t \leq b_1 \\
        % s_2
        0.1 & \mathrm{if }\; b_1 < Y_t \leq b_2\\[6pt]
        ... & \mathrm{if }\; ...
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

where $b_0$, $b_1$ etc. are set of quantity intervals = [0, 50, 100, 150,..]

Since we don't have the values of $y$ until at the point where objective function is specified (cause value of decision variables) are only available once we give call to optimize m.optimize(). So, how we could program this in Python interface.

Any leads will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `r_t(Y_t)` is a constant for a specific value of Y_t, so  `(1-r_t)*Y_t` is a piecewise linear function. You should use the piecewise linear objective feature in Gurobi; some other solvers also have a similar feature.

Comment: Could you please provide any clue as to how to use piecewise linear objective for this problem in Gurobi. I am struggling to form one and can't relate with reference examples.